# Could anyone please help me solve this differential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$b∙v_Y^2/m-dv_Y/dt=g$$

$v_Y$ here simply means vertical velocity, b is coefficient for drag force, g is the gravity constant. For $v_Y$ , you may simply regard this as $x$ or other variables. I don't think it would affect calculations.

I don't know the steps but I know the answer to this differential. I have attached the image of the answer below. Please teach me the steps to the answer.

[image]

To explain a bit about the image, $V_{yi}$ stands for the initial velocity and $V_t'$ stands for the terminal velocity.

here $V_t'=(mg/b)^{.5}$

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. What have you tried so far? Do you know how to solve differential equations through separation of variables?

Comment: If you take $u_Y$ as $y$, then your equation becomes a non-linear first order ODE $~y'=(b/m)y^2+g~.$ Now solve this equation by separation of variable method.

Comment: OHHH it is far easier than I thought. Seperation of variables it works. Thank You so much. I was busy making some random characteristic equations which don't even make sense:D